# AWS Cognito: Change the value of users' custom field

Tags: android, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm working on my project and making an android app using Cognito for user management.

I tried to use it as user database so I made some custom fields like age and picture_url. **But I cannot find a way to change the value of a custom field.** I found the code to delete the value of field but couldn't find the one to register to an existing user.

Is it impossible to change the value of a custom field from android or lambda in python so that I need to switch to RDS to store user information?

Answer (score 1):

The Python SDK method which should work for this is `CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.update_user_attributes` ([Python SDK AWS Docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.update_user_attributes))

For the attribute name be sure to prefix it with `custom:` (`custom:age` and `custom:picture_url` for the attributes you mentioned). The custom prefix is mentioned here: [AWS Docs: Configuring User Pool Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-custom-attributes)

If you are using Client based access be sure the Client has access to modify the custom attributes. I don't believe clients which exist prior to the custom attribute being created automatically have access to modify the newly created attribute.